# MediaPlayer error: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.media.MediaPlayer.start()' on a null object reference

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-mediaplayer

I'm trying to make an app to play music files from the internal storage of the phone.

This is the first method where all the songs are listed in a ListView.

```
    public void fileSearch() {
    String[] loadSongs = {MediaStore.Audio.Media._ID, MediaStore.Audio.Media.DISPLAY_NAME};
    Cursor audioCursor = getContentResolver().query(MediaStore.Audio.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, loadSongs, null, null, null);
    if (audioCursor != null) {
        if (audioCursor.moveToFirst()) {
            do {
                int audioIndex = audioCursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Audio.Media.DISPLAY_NAME);

                audioList.add(audioCursor.getString(audioIndex));
            } while (audioCursor.moveToNext());
        }
    }
    audioCursor.close();
    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, android.R.id.text1, audioList);
    listSongs.setAdapter(adapter);
    listSongs.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            selectedSong(position);
        }
    });



}
```

And this method should be playing the song selected by the user in the previous list.

```
 public void selectedSong(int position) {
    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, android.R.id.text1, audioList);
    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "You  have selected the song:" + adapter.getItem(position), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    File songSelectedPath = getFileStreamPath(adapter.getItem(position));

    Uri uri = Uri.fromFile(songSelectedPath);
    Log.d("Adapter", "AdapterToStringPath: " + uri);
    Log.d("Pointer", "Pointer: " + position);

    MediaPlayer mediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer();
    mediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(this,uri);
    mediaPlayer.start();
}
```

The error comes from this line *mediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(this,uri);*

```
Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.media.MediaPlayer.start()' on a null object reference
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is you are adding an invalid path to the **MediaPlayer**. To get the correct path you can use Cursor to find the name of your selected songs and get its path. in short I have to modify the signature of your method in order to send the name of the file directly without passing again by the adapter this is the method :

```
public void selectedSong(String songName) {
    String[] loadSongs = {MediaStore.Audio.Media.DATA, MediaStore.Audio.Media.DISPLAY_NAME};
    String selection1 = MediaStore.Audio.Media.DISPLAY_NAME + " = ?";
    String[] selectionArgs = new String[]{songName};
    Cursor audioCursor = getContentResolver().query(MediaStore.Audio.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, loadSongs, selection1, selectionArgs, null);

    if (audioCursor != null) {
        if (audioCursor.moveToFirst()) {
            int audioIndex = audioCursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Audio.Media.DATA);
            String path = audioCursor.getString(audioIndex);
            Log.e("TAG", "selectedSong: " + path);
            Uri uri = Uri.fromFile(new File(path));
            Log.d("Adapter", "AdapterToStringPath: " + uri);
            MediaPlayer mediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer();
            Log.e("TAG", "selectedSong: " + uri);
            mediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(this, uri);
            mediaPlayer.start();
        }
    }
```

and on your listener call it like below :

```
   listSongs.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                selectedSong(audioList.get(position));
            }
        });
```

The method that I have mounted above may not work correctly let's imagine we have a file of the same *`Name`* on different *`Folders`* in this case it is quite possible that you are mistaken on a file because we will get the *`file path`* from its *`name`*.

So I suggest you create an `Object` which contains the *`Filename`* and the *`Path`* and add it to the `list of songs`, to display an item you need the *`Dispalyed_Name`* and when you click on a song  you get the *`Path`* I think it's easier to do. do not hesitate to leave a comment if you did not understand what I suggested

Comment: Thank you @Shay Kin it worked! Now I'm going to create the object as you suggested.